# Animate images on slides in a Kivy carousel

Tags: python, kivy

I have a Kivy carousel and each slide contains a float layout with an image and some labels on it. When I move to the next slide I want the image to animate. I am not using KV language for specific reasons, I am doing everything in python script.

[image]

I can get animation working so long as I don't try to position the widget I want to animate within the float layout. As soon as I position the widget it will not animate anymore.

Clearly positioning the widget locks it in place and it can't move anymore so can't be animated. How do I get the effect that I want?

Here is some working code that illustrates the problem.

```
import kivy     
from kivy.app import App  
from kivy.uix.carousel import Carousel 
from kivy.uix.image import AsyncImage  
from kivy.animation import Animation
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout

def animate():
    animation = Animation(pos=(20, 0), t='out_bounce')
    animation += Animation(pos=(-40, 0), t='out_bounce')
    animation += Animation(pos=(0, 0), t='out_bounce')
    return animation

class MyCarousel(Carousel):
    # This class is a carousel that runs script
    # when a slide gets focus (except first load).
    def on_index(self, *args):
        print('the slide is', self.index)
        # 1 is image, 0 is label
        animate().start(self.current_slide.children[1])
        Carousel.on_index(self, *args)

class CarouselApp(App): 
    def build(self): 
        # Set carousel widget as root 
        root = MyCarousel()  

        # Adding slides 
        for i in range(3): 
            flo = FloatLayout() # to test nesting animation
            src = "https://via.placeholder.com/480x270.png&text=slide-%d" %i             
            image = AsyncImage(source = src, allow_stretch = True) 
            hello = Label(text='Hello', font_size=50)

            # THESE KILL ANIMATION -----------------
            # image.pos_hint = {'x': 0.25, 'y': 0.25}
            # hello.pos_hint = {'bottom': 1, 'left': 1}
            # --------------------------------------

            image.size_hint = (0.5, 0.5)
            hello.size_hint = (0.25, 0.25)
            flo.add_widget(image)
            flo.add_widget(hello)
            root.add_widget(flo) 

        return root 
  
# run the App 
if __name__ == '__main__': 
    #breakpoint()
    app = CarouselApp()
    app.run()
```

If you run this script it will animate the image. Changing the `self.current_slide.children[k]` subscript will animate the label. But as soon as you uncomment the `pos_hint` parameters the animation won't work anymore.

Comment: The `pos_hint` values take precedence over `pos` values. So animating `pos` with `pos_hint` set to anything will not work.  You can position your Widgets using `pos` instead of `pos_hint`, and then animation will work.

Comment: Or you could animate the `pos_hint` property.

Comment: Thanks John, how would i go about animating pos_hint, that is beyond my current knowledge and any help would be appreciated. I tried ```animate().start(self.current_slide.children[1].pos_hint) ``` but didn't expect it to work and it doesn't.

Comment: Following John's suggestion about using ```pos``` instead of ```pos_hint``` the animation works. Basically you just peg the position of a widget to its container, a float layout in my case. So the code is ```image.pos = flo.center``` and ```hello.pos = flo.pos```. This is very specific to my situation so i am hoping for a more general solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To animate `pos_hint`, you must specify that property when you create the animation. For example:

```
def animate():
    animation = Animation(pos_hint={'x':.5, 'y':0}, t='out_bounce')
    animation += Animation(pos_hint={'x':-.2, 'y':0}, t='out_bounce')
    animation += Animation(pos_hint={'x':0, 'y':0}, t='out_bounce')
    return animation
```

Now you can use the `pos_hint` to specify the starting position, as your commented out code does:

```
        image.pos_hint = {'x': 0.25, 'y': 0.25}
        hello.pos_hint = {'bottom': 1, 'left': 1}
```

Three things to note:

1. The `pos_hint` keys `bottom` and `left` are not valid. Legal keys are ‘x’, ‘right’, ‘center_x’, ‘y’, ‘top’ and ‘center_y’.
2. You must animate the keys that you initially use to position the widget. If you animate the `center_x` hint, but `center_x` is not in the initial `pos_hint`, then it will have no effect.
3. The `pos_hint` takes precedence over `pos`, so animating `pos` of a widget that is originally positioned using `pos_hint`, will have no effect.